# Prevent Assembly Name to changes every run

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

As stated in the title i have that strange behaviour with the subsequent call

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
```

My exe name is CoreService.exe, with the call above i get different response every time i call it eg :

1. Coreservice.exe
2. CoreService.exe
3. CoreService.Exe
4. Coreservice.Exe
5. Coreservice.EXE
6. CoreService.EXE

I get this behaviour working on Windows Server 2012 and only when i start my CoreService as windows service instead of windows process, anybody can explain why of that strange thing ?

Comment: Interesting question, however how is this behavior affecting you?

Comment: To be clear, what changes between each run? Are you always using the same exe or are you e.g. rebuilding it between runs?

Answer (score 1):

Actually `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name` does not include the extension.

> AssemblyName.Name Property
>
> Gets or sets the
>   simple name of the assembly. This is usually, but not necessarily, the
>   file name of the manifest file of the assembly, minus its extension.

Or then you have actually hit the "but not necessarily" part of it... which would be the first I have ever heard of.

If this is the case, and you need to do something about it besides being curious, then you could ensure consistent result.

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);
```